# Is it possible to programmatically access the Apple Maps navigation history?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have to retrieve the Apple Maps navigation history. In other words, is there a way of retrieving the recent routes searched by the user of the Apple Maps app? I need recent searches in HomeKit app(in iOS 10).

Comment: no, is not possible

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik have you seen in any documentation for "History" ?

Comment: @datha are you found any answer ?

Comment: I stored( in Nsuserdefaults ) keywords searched in **my app** and retrieved when required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available to get information out of the Navigation App. But you can feed some data to Maps to request a route through an Intent / URI.

But I don't think that the Maps app will save the whole route anyway, only the destination. The user selects any saved destination and you can get there from any source.